# Understanding Ruby open classes

Tags: ruby

I am trying to understand the working of ruby open classes. In particular how does a method gets added to an existing class?

There must be some logic applied to identify if the class already exists.

Can someone please explain the concept.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean how the `class` keyword is implemented to see if the class already exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class names are constants, so it's fairly easy to see if a class name already exists:

```
Object.constants.grep(/Array/) #=> ["Array"]
```

So if a class is already defined (`Object.const_get('Array').is_a? Class`) the methods get added to it, otherwise a new class gets defined. To be a bit more precise this happens on the C side of Ruby, but is more or less what it boils down to.

Answer (score 2):

Underneath Ruby, there are messages.

Suppose you've a class `A`, and `a` is an instance of `A`. There actually are several classes involved:

```
Basic Object
-> Object
-> A
-> a
```

When you call method foo on `a`, what's really happening is you're sending the message "call foo" to `a`. It checks if the instance method is defined for `a` (as in, the singleton/eigenclass), then tries instance methods of `A`, then `Object`, and finally `Basic Object`. If all else fails, the VM sends a new message (i.e. "method not found") and the procedure starts again until it gets caught (by default, it raises an exception).

You can add a new method (i.e. a message handler) to any of the classes in the hierarchy, in order to change the behavior of `a`. If you add an instance method to `A` or `Object`, then `a` will have it. If you add a method to `a` only (i.e. `def a.bar; 'bar'; end`), then other instances of `A` will have it.

Ruby's classes (I'd argue it would more appropriate to say ruby's objects) are open in the sense that you can add these new methods, i.e. message handlers, at any point in time -- including long after they've been defined.